# Cardano DB Sync - RTS Options

Tags: haskell, cabal, cardano-db-sync, ubuntu

After successfully with [previous question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/7435/6616), where I tried to make `cardano-node` and `cardano-db-sync` run as a services, I tried to play around with `+RTS ... -RTS` option on `cardano-db-sync`, specifically to reduce the RAM consumption with some option.

Here's the RTS option I tried `+RTS -N2 -A16m -qa -qb -qg -M6000M -RTS`.

With `cardano-node run ...`, I can do above RTS options, but with `cardano-db-sync ...`, I couldn't, here's the sample command

```
...
...
...
PGPASSFILE=${PGPASSFILE} cardano-db-sync +RTS -N2 -A16m -qa -qb -qg -M4500M -RTS --config ${CONFIG} --socket-path ${CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH} --state-dir ${STATE_DIR} --schema-dir ${SCHEMA_DIR}
```

But, it fails, the error shown as below

```
Mar 08 09:54:54 cardano-db-sync: Most RTS options are disabled. Link with -rtsopts to enable them.
Mar 08 09:54:54 cardano-db-sync-run.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 08 09:54:54 cardano-db-sync-run.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried to add `-rtsopts` as suggested on that error, but it also fails

```
PGPASSFILE=${PGPASSFILE} cardano-db-sync +RTS -N2 -A16m -qa -qb -qg -M4500M -RTS -rtsopts --config ${CONFIG} --socket-path ${CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH} --state-dir ${STATE_DIR} --schema-dir ${SCHEMA_DIR}
```

Same error is shown

```
cardano-db-sync: Most RTS options are disabled. Link with -rtsopts to enable them.
```

Also, I tried to do that with another way (reference - [on official documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html?highlight=rtsopts)), `-with-rtsopts="-N2 -A16m -qa -qb -qg -M6000M"`, but it also fails with error, as shown below

```
Invalid option `-with-rtsopts=-N2 -A16m -qa -qb -qg -M4500M'
```

---

Is it possible to add the options `+RTS ... -RTS` like I tried above?

Or, am I did wrong? Like, it must come sequentially right after/before some command?

Thanks in advance! And, have a great day!

---

*PS

- The reason I did try to reduce the RAM consumption is because `cardano-node run` and `cardano-db-sync` keeps dropped (killed) from the services, since I had limited RAM (16GB) on my test server. I kinda aware with RAM requirement, but I tried to reduce it, due some circumstances, I can't upgrade RAM on my test server, since it has `cardano node` running too.
- I'm not GHC expert or even linux expert. So, if there's some terms or RTS option that I use incorrectly, please let me know, so I can do in a correct way. :)

Comment: I am the main developer on `db-sync`. Trying to reduce the memory footprint of `db-sync` using RTS options will fail with 100% certainty.

The problem is that both `node` and `db-sync` have a data structure called ledger state (which is huge, like 8 Gigabytes huge) that is basically identical. Long term, we want to reduce that so that `db-sync` does not need to maintain that. Until then, you need to just live with the high memory usage.

Comment: Hi @ErikdeCastroLopo - thanks for your comment & explanation. Want to confirm for your statement - "Trying to reduce the memory footprint of db-sync using RTS options will fail with 100% certainty." - is that meant I couldn't use RTS options, like I used on `cardano-node run`? || And, "Until then, you need to just live with the high memory usage." - you mean, the **only way** is to upgrade RAM?

Comment: `RTS` options might allow you to shave as much as 20% off the memory usage at the cost of a performance hit (because the garbage collector will need to run more often). Unfortunately the only current solution is more RAM.

Comment: Do you know what `RTS` options that might be available for me to use? since, from what I test around from initial options `+RTS -N2 -A16m -qa -qb -qg -M6000M -RTS` it gives me error message `Most RTS options are disabled. Link with -rtsopts to enable them.`. Anyway, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Oh, sorry, `RTS` opts are disabled by default in the `db-sync` build.

To enable it add `-rtsopts` after `-with-rtsopts=-N3` for the `cardano-db-sync` executable in the file `cardano-db-sync/cardano-db-sync.cabal`

Comment: Thanks for your guide! seems it kinda works, but unsure if it will fail or not, since I just started the `cardano-node run` again, so it needs time to catch-up. Have a great day! :)

Comment: It will like work really well for the vast majority of the mainnet chain. You are really only likely to run into problems later on the chain where there is just orders of magnitude more data on the chain.

Comment: Ahh yes.. I tried to tweak around the RTS options, but on some options, it will be dropped (service killed since it needs more RAM consumption). Anyway, your comment to add "-rtsopts" is correct, do you mind to `post it as answer` perhaps? so I can mark it as the correct answer on this post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RTS` opts are disabled by default in the db-sync build. To enable it add `-rtsopts` after `-with-rtsopts=-N3` for the `cardano-db-sync` executable in the file `cardano-db-sync/cardano-db-sync.cabal`.

Comment: thanks for this! hope the others will got help in the future!